# How do I update a user's rating in JSP and/or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, radio-button

I am not terribly familiar with either tech, so bear with me.
I have a set of radio buttons on my jsp page. They are valued 1-5. I would like to update that new rating to the database.
I know that I have to somehow utilize the "onselect" event, but I haven't found anything that helps. 
Does anyone have an idea as how to accomplish this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have included spring-mvc in you tags, I am assuming you would like some more information about sending information from client side to the server.

If your are just using JSP, and a standard form, if you match the 'commandName' and the 'method' to your controller in spring, the controller will catch the parameters sent through the form:

```
<form id="form" commandName="interceptedPath" method="post">
    <input id="rating1" type="radio" name="rating" value="1" checked><label for="rating1">1</label>
    <input id="rating2" type="radio" name="rating" value="2"><label for="rating2">2</label>
    <input id="rating3" type="radio" name="rating" value="3"><label for="rating3">3</label>
    <input id="rating4" type="radio" name="rating" value="4"><label for="rating4">4</label>
    <input id="rating5" type="radio" name="rating" value="5"><label for="rating5">5</label>
</form>
```

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/interceptedPath/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String submit(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
     Map<String, String[]> parameterMap = request.getParameterMap();
     String[] strings = parameterMap.get("rating")
     return "detailedCalc";
 }
```

JavaScript should not be required unless you are doing something dynamic, like Ajax calls. If you do decide to use Javascript I suggest you use the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").submit(function () {
        $.post('/spring/locationOfAjaxController', $(this).serialize(),
            function (data) {
        }
    }
}
```

For the code above, after the document has loaded on the client. An event is created that will catch all 'submit' actions on the "form" object (note the id for the form is "form"). Once that occurs jQuery will submit a POST to the specified URL. `$(this).serialize()` will serialize the form data into JSON, which will need to be handled by the server.

If you want to do something using **change**, refer to [this reference](http://api.jquery.com/change/).

You can find an excellent example of spring-mvc (without js) using maven archetype: `org.fluttercode.knappsack:spring-mvc-jpa-demo-archetype`. It will generate a basic project that has spring-mvc already set up and ready to go.

Comment: And suppose I use the purely Spring MVC route. I should be able to attach parameters for the IDs related to who is doing the rating and what is being rated, correct?

Comment: @user1281598 For users and sessions I would suggest using spring security it will keep track of the users, their roles, and other essential information. Instead of passing a user id from the client to the server; it'd be best if the server keep track of the users information. Spring security would have the users information, while the bit of code `  String[] strings = parameterMap.get("rating")` would hold the actual value the user rated the item at. [Spring-Security-tutorial](http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/spring-security-3-mvc-using-secured.html)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it isn't a form:

1. Detect in javascript the change
2. post it to your server side script
3. maybe process it and update the database

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to use the `onchange` and set it to a function that will read the `select` tag. The function should look similar to below.

```
function ratingChange(ele){
   var opt = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;  
   var txt = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text; 
   //process values and test
   //assuming the form is not submitting use AJAX
}
```

The `onchange` would then look like this.

`<select name="rating" onchange="ratingChange(this)">`